# Oblique projection onto a plane.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

I need to find the projection of $X$ on the plane $N\cdot(P - R) = 0$, where $P$ is some point on the plane and $N$ is the normal of the plane, along the direction $D$, such that $N\cdot D \ne 0$.

Let the point of projection be $Y = X + dD$ for some $d$, then $Y - P = (X - P) + dD$. Taking dot product with $N$ on both sides and using the fact that $Y$ lies on the given plane, $d = -\dfrac{N\cdot(X - P)}{N\cdot D}$.

$$\therefore Y = X - \dfrac{N\cdot(X - P)}{N\cdot D} D \tag 1$$

In my book the answer is given as $$Y = \left(I - \dfrac{DN^T}{D^TN} \right)X + \left(\dfrac{DN^T}{D^TN}\right) P \tag 2$$ where $I$ is identity matrix of dimension 3x3.

Questions:-

1. In $(2)$ matrix $A = DN^T$ is divided by matrix $B = D^TN$ but matrix multiplication is not commutative, so $\dfrac{A}{B} = AB^{-1} \text{ or } A^{-1}B$ ?
2. How to simplify $(1)$ to get $(2)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in the book it is assumed that $D$, $P$, $X$, $N$ are column vectors, which is the same as $3\times 1$ matrices. Therefore, we have
$$
N\cdot D = D^T N = N^T D
$$
which is simply a number. No need to worry about non-commutative matrix multiplication.
$$
Y =  X-\frac{N\cdot (X-P)}{N\cdot D} D \\
  =  X-\frac{ D (N\cdot (X-P))}{N\cdot D} \\
  =  X-\frac{ D N^T(X-P)}{D^T N} \\
  =  X-\frac{ D N^TX-D N^TP}{D^T N} \\
  =  X-\frac{ D N^TX}{D^T N} +\frac{D N^TP}{D^T N} \\
  =  \left( I -\frac{ D N^T}{D^T N}\right) X+\left(\frac{D N^T}{D^T N}\right)P
$$